# How to create a folder in iOS application Home Page

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsfilemanager, nsfilecoordinator

Is there is any tutorial to explain folder creation in iOS app?

In My application there is a home page contain different type of document. I want to arrange documents in folder with respect to the type of documents. can any one help?

Comment: please did you read about NSFileManager read this http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_on_the_iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to create folders in your Application's Document directory folder:

```
- (void)createFolderWithName:(NSString *)aName {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                YES) lastObject];
    NSString *folder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aName];

    // Create the folder if necessary
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder
                       isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder
           withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                            attributes:nil
                                 error:nil];
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In order to list all folders in your document directory you need to first get list of all the files/folders and then use a UITableView to display them, when user clicks on a sub-folder then you repeat the process with updated path. For details go through this [Source Code](https://github.com/pixelrevision/ios_file_browser)

Comment: asifmujteba thanks for your answer. But my need is to create and show folder in the application screen itself

Comment: do you want to know how to list all the folders on the screen ?

Comment: you are develop app and IOS not display folder on itself. what is home screen..? that create by you not by ios so you have to manage your self not folder disply it self @Mary

Comment: asifmujteba  yes thats my need

Comment: Thanks asifmujteba. your answer help me to complete my work :-)